# Can I post a statistics related question here that got no answer in 'Mathematics'?

Tags: discussion

A few months ago I posted a question over at https://math.stackexchange.com/.

The [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1600069/error-in-distance-between-points-in-spherical-coordinates) is related to error analysis, and it got no answer over there.

Is it acceptable to re-post it here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normal approach would be to migrate, but I think it would be past the migration cut-off time.

I think in that case posting here would be okay.

Comment: Thank you Glen, I'll probably post it here tomorrow.